# How do I use the Postgresql ANY operator in a NOT IN statement

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Using Pyscopg2, how do I pass a Python list into an SQL statement [using the ANY Operator](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation)?

Normal Working SQL reads ([See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9c943/8)):

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE id NOT IN (3);
```

Using Psycopg2 as below:

**Psycopg2: Query 1**

The query below fails with `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ANY"`

```
id_list = [2,3,4]
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id NOT IN ANY(%s)) %(id_list);
```

**Psycopg2: Query 2**

The query below  doesn't throw an error but it gives a wrong result because it doesn't exclude the IDs in the list. It behaves as if its an Equal To operator or to be specific like its an `IN` statement while I want a `NOT IN`

```
id_list = [2,3,4]
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id != ANY(%s)), (id_list,);
```

Also, in my search I've come across [pyscopg2 extension SQL_IN](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.SQL_IN). Can it be used in this situation? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do

```
select 2 != any(array[2,3,4]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

`2` will be compared to all array items and if there is any to which `2` is not equal it will evaluate to `true`.

Use `not id = any(array[2,3,4])`

```
select not 1 = any(array[2,3,4]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t

select not 2 = any(array[2,3,4]);
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Or `!= all`

```
select 1 != all(array[2,3,4]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t

select 2 != all(array[2,3,4]);
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Comment: not id = any(...) don't return null value so if you want null use un addition or id is null

Answer (score 0):

The `SQL_IN` adapter makes it possible to use the `IN` operator by adapting a *tuple*, not a list (lists are adapted to PostgreSQL arrays). To make your query work you should write the code as follows:

```
id_list = (2,3,4) # Note the tuple!
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id NOT IN %s", (id_list,));
```

Comment: How do I configure the cursor to use the `SQL_IN` adapter in the first place?

Comment: It' already configured by default. It is the default adapter for lists.