# Efficiently check if a value is in a set of known values

Tags: postgresql

Out of a large collection of rows in a table, I want to pick one that isn't a member of a particular set of recently-used rows. The set is maintained as a list of IDs. My current code looks like this:

```
used = [123,234,345,456,567]
cur.execute("select id from tracks order by id=any(%s), random()", [used])
```

(Python + psycopg2; the %s transforms into ARRAY[...] when it's sent to Postgres.)

The PG docs caution me that arrays are not sets, which suggests that the "=any" check is a linear search. Is there a tidier and/or more efficient way to express this?

Comment: Try using a tuple and the NOT IN operator, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26968571/838308).

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that would be faster. The Python tuple becomes a Postgres ROW,and I can't find anything indicating that that behaves as a set, although there's also nothing that says that it can't. Do you know for sure? If you can find a link, post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't see proof-positive of this fact, but [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/) specifically mention that NOT IN is much faster than a list of equivalent AND queries. I'm pretty confident the database implementors would have gotten the easy hashing speedup when the data size matters - this is the idiomatic way to do what you're doing, after all. Note that for small tuples like yours, iterating over the list is probably faster, though. This isn't the place to optimize unless it turns out to be a real hot spot.

Comment: The list in my post is purely an example. In the code, the list's length varies (each iteration of this code, the ID gets added to the "recently used" collection); currently I have it bounded at 50 elements, which is easily short enough for a linear search, but future versions could change that. I'm going to keep it as-is for now (since the use of a tuple would incur other costs), but link to this question.

Comment: Huh. Out of curiosity, why would using a tuple incur other costs? If you're referring to the time to construct of the tuple from the list of ids, IMO that cost is insignificant compared to any of a) the network cost of the RPC to the database, b) the cost of actually executing a query on the database, and c) the benefits of using an idiomatic query. The reason for the ANY syntax is that it supports other operators. If you just want to check if something is in a list, use IN.

Comment: Because the rest of the code is adding and removing from the collection - in Python, tuples are immutable. Here's the code in question: https://github.com/MikeiLL/appension/pull/224/files

Comment: Or are you saying I should maintain the list as a list, then convert to a tuple just before giving it to Postgres? That would be about as costly as a linear search of the original array, I would expect.